# in C# how to rotate picturebox with its image?

Tags: c#, winforms

i am developing C# application in that i have to rotate whole picturebox with its iamge, i use rotateFlip() method but it only support 90,180,270 degrees and i want it for 1 degree

Comment: Wait, what? You wish to rotate teh actual PictureBox control, or just the Image inside?

Comment: total pictureBox along with image

Comment: I dont think you can *rotate* the PictureBox control. You can rotate the pixture within it though. Why do you wish to rotate the control?

Comment: If i go to rotate only image from pictureBox then image rotate in pictureBox and it looks cut so i want to rotate image with whole pictureBox

Comment: Yes, that is what happens when you rotate squares. Why not make the PictureBox bigger that the actual image size, so that it will fit at any angle?

Comment: i tested with maximum size but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
 img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
 pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer a bit, instead of just posting the code.

Comment: Code is so simple that no explanation required. `RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone` will rotate image at 90 degree without flipping. Simple !

Answer (score -1):

```c#
PIC_LOAD.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
PIC_LOAD.Refresh();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).